# How to count records with hour within range

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jodatime

I have a Jasper Reports requirement to count the number of records for which the hour component of a date field is within a range from 18:00 hours to 06:00 hours.  I have created a summed variable with the following structure:

```
new Integer( ( ((new org.joda.time.DateTime($F{CCDateDis}).getHourOfDay()) > 18) &&
               ((new org.joda.time.DateTime($F{CCDateDis}).getHourOfDay()) < 6)
) ? 1 : 0)
```

Where $F{CCDateDis} is a Date() object.

The variable sum always returns '0' even though I know that there are records that fall within this range.  Is there something that I am missing here?

Comment: The [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24348312/642706) is correct. But a separate issue is time zone. This code implicitly applies the JVM's default time zone when constructing the DateTime. So results will vary across various computers or will vary if the host OS or JVM has its time zone settings changed. I suggest specifying the desired time zone as a second argument to constructor.

Comment: That is a good point - thank you.  In fact this is related to a query about the time patients are discharged from an acute ward to a normal ward - so it it the actual time that is important (regardless of timezone).  The point is that there is evidence that discharges after 6.00 PM are associated with a higher mortality rate... just on the side but I thought you might be interested..

Comment: All the more reason to specify a time zone. If the computer's/JVM's default changes the results of your reports and analysis *will change*. This can happen if someone changes the time zone and can even happen with modern operating systems that automatically set time zone based on geolocation (and that location is not always correct). Working with date-time data without explicit time zones is like working with temperature data without explicitly noting if it is in Fahrenheit or Celsius.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I will modify the code to include the timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse the comparisons.

Your logic is basically:

```
x > 18 && x < 6
```

This is mathematically always false - there is no number that is both greater than 18 *and* less than 6.

Change the logic to:

```
x <= 18 && x >= 6
```

Comment: That is embarrassing!  I guess that it is easy to get confused working with a 24 hour cycle.  Thank you.